# App crashes when button is pressed for alertdialog to pop up

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

so anyway, i'm try to make an app for learning purposes cause im fairly new to android. I'm making it so that when you press on the enter button, a pop up alert dialog come up and prompts the user to enter their login details and move onto the next page. The problem is, the app keep crashing once the button is pressed. This is my code

```
public void diaryPageBtn(View view) {
    showAlertDialog();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DiaryPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void showAlertDialog() {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(
            R.layout.login_dialog, null);
    final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
    deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your business logic 
            deleteDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    deleteDialog.show();
}
```

I know that the alert dialog function works fine, its just that it won't move onto the next page. Thats really whats important for me and i'm pretty sure i can figure everything else out from there. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use positive and negative buttons, that come with alert dialog? instead of the buttons you have in your layout?

Comment: Can you precise the error? The issue might come from the fact that you are launching the new activity just after showing your dialod. Shouldn't you do this once the dialog is dismissed?